# Cygwin Command giving error

Tags: javascript, shell, command

## For a maplestory test server

Having troubles with the cygwin shell and my dir is C:/FakeMaple with some server files inside the folder

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

while getopts ":d" opt; do
  case $opt in
    d)
      ant_args="-Ddebug=true"
      ;;
```

### `\?)`

```
script/server -d
```

[Returns error saying i didn't write the letter 's'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9Zm8.png)

Clearly the letter s is right there.
How do i make it so it writes script/server -d

Comment: Can you give is the first ten line of server pls?

Comment: Can you format that into a code block so we can see it properly?

Comment: trying my best new here sorry

Comment: No worries, thanks ))

Answer (score 0):

Ok the complaint about \r is referring to the carridge-return character. I cannot tell from your output of `server` here but you may have line ending issues.

If you're editting this script on Win and *nix maybe you've mashed your line endings.

In *nix lines ought to end with only the line feed character.

Open this file on Win with Notepad++, im View menu turn on all line ending characters and see what's going on. There's also a menu item to correct endings to Win or *nix style.

Comment: i am seeing some weird stuff I don't know what's going on http://prntscr.com/9on5ub you see the unicode how do i get rid of it? Or no need?

Comment: Ok in ur screenshot all the lines are ending with CR LF with is great on Windows. There's no eroneous CR or LF on their own.

Comment: I'm not sure but try converting all to just LF using Notepad++ and rerunning script.